# How to make psql editor show line number

Tags: psql

New to the VIM. Environment: WSL2
Already set VIM to show line number, It works as expected. So I type vi `test.txt` in Ubuntu/WSL2, it will show line number.

But In psql, when I type `\e` It will not show line number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `sudo su` to enter root mode.
2. `sudo -u postgres -i`
   After logging as user postgres in Ubuntu then using
3. `vim ~/.vimrc`  to create/edit a new vimrc file.